# A bug preventing iPhone audio from reverting to speaker mode after unplugging headphones

Tags: iphone, audio, headphones, bug

I encountered a weird glitch with my iPhone while listening to a Youtube video over headphones. One of the earbuds shorted out (they're old and somewhat damaged), so I unplugged the headphones and tried to continue listening to the video over the iPhone's built-in speakers, but there was no sound. Also, I noticed then that the Youtube video failed to auto-pause when I disconnected the headphones, which is what normally happens. I then went to idiot-check the volume level using the buttons on the left side of the device, and low and behold, the volume bar display that pops up indicated that headphone volume was being adjusted instead of speaker volume.

So my questions are how exactly did my phone become deluded into thinking that headphones are jacked in the first place, and, of course, how might I resolve this problem?

(And before anyone asks, no I haven't tried turning it off and on again, yet. That very likely will fix the problem, but where's the fun in that? The glitch made me curious, and I wanted to see if there was anything I could from it first. =) )

Comment: Grubby connection in the phone jack would be my first suspect - it simply hasn't 'seen' the unplug yet. Jamming the plug [gently] in & out might just clear it - but I'm not sure I'd do that with the phone switched on.

Comment: Um ... restarting any failing device is the second troubleshooting question after "Is it plugged into a power source." Also, you might want to blow into the jack to dislodge any crud inside. Don't use your own breath as spit may get into the jack - try one of the 'cans of air' photographers use.